# error CS0201, What is this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

```
public static void EchoAsync(
string param1, string param2, string key, string secret, Service.OnSuccess success, Service.OnFailed failed)

{

    BackgroundWorker worker = Service.CreateWorkerAsync(success, failed);
    worker.DoWork += (o, args) => (args.Result = Echo(param1, param2, key, secret));     //(Line4)
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

When I build this , "error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" occurs on Line 4.

I'm new to C# and I can't know How to solve this...

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Uses {curly braces} instead of (parentheses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
(o, args) => (args.Result = Echo(param1, param2, key, secret));
```

with

```
(o, args) => {args.Result = Echo(param1, param2, key, secret); };
```

which makes it a statement lambda instead of an expression lambda.

---

In C# the assignment operator is a valid expression and could be returned, which the expression lambda does.  But then your lambda's return type would not be `void`... making it incompatible with the `DoWork` event.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra set of parenthesis around your lambda.

```
worker.DoWork += (o, args) => (args.Result = Echo(param1, param2, key, secret));
```

should be

```
worker.DoWork += (o, args) => args.Result = Echo(param1, param2, key, secret);
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter... `return x;` and `return (x);` are equivalent.  And neither are good in an event handler, which shouldn't return anything.

Comment: `() => x = 1` and `() => (x = 1)` aren't equivalent though, and neither of them return a value.